# Using RegexSerde to define multiline input format

Tags: regex, hive

My input looks like this

```
-----------
name=name1
add=add1 
EOE 
-----------
name=name2
add=add2
EOE
```

This is what I tried but the table doesn't populate anything...

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE testrawtext (
    name   string, 
    address string
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
     "input.regex" = "-*\\n.+=(.*)\\n.+=(.*)[\\s\\S]*?\\nEOE") 
LOCATION 's3://test-athena-raw-text/testrawtext';
```

Is there something wrong with my regex?

Comment: Your regex seems fine. Are you sure the code is working by itself? Can you try with something simpler like `(.+)=(.+)`? Don't you need `STORED AS TEXTFILE;`? Did you check your `LOCATION`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm not sure but could it be because hive doesn't support multiline records? May be it tries to apply the regex only on the first line, fails and populates the tables as empty. I couldn't find a concrete source